# Returning AM/PM with IntlDateTimeFormat

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm using the `IntlDateTimeFormat` with some date and time options. However, I'm having difficulties getting the format I want at the end.

Below is the code I currently have. The result I'm after is to return a string with the following formatting:

`Sept 27, 2022 at 12:20 PM`

So far, the current code is returning:

`27 Sept 2022 at 12:20`

Note the `AM/PM` missing (capitalised would be great too)

```
  public dateOptions = {
    month: 'short',
    year: 'numeric',
    day: '2-digit',
  } as const;

  public timeOptions = {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    dayPeriod: 'narrow',
  } as const;

  private newDateString() {
    const now = new Date();
    const tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale;
    const date = Intl.DateTimeFormat(tz, this.dateOptions).format(now);
    const time = Intl.DateTimeFormat(tz, this.timeOptions).format(now);
    return `${date}` + ' at ' + `${time}`;
  }
```

Comment: `dayPeriod: 'narrow'` will return `"at night"` or something like that change it to `hour12: true `

Comment: FYI - ```return `${date}` + ' at ' + `${time}`;``` would be better written ```return `${date} at ${time}`;``` You're using template literals anyway, might as well make full use of them.

Comment: Or `return date + ' at ' + time`, which is exactly the same number of characters to write. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dayPeriod: 'narrow'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#dayperiod) The formatting style used for day periods like "in the morning", "am", "noon", "n" etc. , change it to [hour12: true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#hour12)

```js
dateOptions = {
  day: '2-digit',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
}
timeOptions = {
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  hour12: true
  //dayPeriod: 'narrow',
}

function newDateString(tz) {
  const now = new Date();
  //const tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale;
  const date = Intl.DateTimeFormat(tz, this.dateOptions).format(now);
  const time = Intl.DateTimeFormat(tz, this.timeOptions).format(now);
  return `${date} at ${time}`;
}
function justAnExampleAsTheOpWatnsThis() {
  const now = new Date();
  const date = Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-GB", this.dateOptions).format(now);
  const time = Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", this.timeOptions).format(now);
  return `${date} at ${time}`;
}
console.log(newDateString("en-US"));
console.log(newDateString("en-GB"));
console.log("Op want this :" + justAnExampleAsTheOpWatnsThis());
```

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that. Thanks! - This is great thank you. Is there a way for the day and month to be swapped around as well as the `pm` or `am` being capitalised?

Comment: @Que DateTimeFormat object enables language-sensitive date and time formatting.
so in your code you have `const tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale;` that is the time zone. You can try `tz = 'en-US'` ; and `tz = ['ban', 'id']`;  just to see the difference.

Comment: @Que, this code gives me "Sep 27, 2022 at 1:06 PM" which matches exactly your requirements. The precise format will depend upon the user's locale.

Comment: Thanks both. Out of curiosity, what makes the `PM` uppercase? Mine appears as 27 Sept 2022 at 1:08 pm (no comma after `sept`)

Comment: @Que may be you are looking for something like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: I've been trying to avoid importing an entire library for one function where possible.

Comment: @Que so if you use tz= "en-GB" fot the date and "en-US" fot the time is exactli the format you want

Comment: That's really useful to know actually, thank you. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

Removed the `dayPeriod: 'narrow'` and then add the option to use time in 12-hours format `hourCycle: 'h12'`.

- `dayPeriod: 'narrow'` would format the time in the text format depends on the locale.
- `hourCycle: 'h12' | 'h11' | 'h23' | 'h24'` would format the time in the 12/24 hours format

```js
var dateOptions = {
    month: 'short',
    year: 'numeric',
    day: '2-digit',
  };

var timeOptions = {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    hourCycle: 'h12'
};

function newDateString() {
    const now = new Date();
    const tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale;
    const date = Intl.DateTimeFormat(tz, this.dateOptions).format(now);
    const time = Intl.DateTimeFormat(tz, this.timeOptions).format(now);
    console.log(`${date}` + ' at ' + `${time}`);
}

newDateString(new Date())
```

Comment: Could do with an explanation of what you changed and why.

Comment: I just removed the `dayPeriod: 'narrow'` and then add the option to use time in 12-hours format `hourCycle: 'h12'`.
`dayPeriod: 'narrow'` would format the time in the text format depends on the locale. 
`hourCycle: 'h12' | 'h11' | 'h23' | 'h24'` would format the time in the 12/24 hours format

Comment: Do you want to edit your answer and put that info there?